# Prove $Aut_F(E)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Perm(X_1)×···×Perm(X_r)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, automorphism-group

Let F be a ﬁeld. Let $f(x) ∈ F[x]$ be a nonzero polynomial, let $E$ be a splitting ﬁeld for $f(x)$ over $F$, and let $X$ denote the set of roots of $f(x)$ in E
Let $f(x)\in F[x]$, and suppose $f(x) = f_1(x)···f_r(x)$ is the factorization of $f(x)$ into irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$.

For each irreducible factor $f_i(x)$, let $X_i$ denote the set of roots of $f_i(x)$ in $E$. May I please ask how to prove that $Aut_F(E)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Perm(X_1)×···×Perm(X_r)$.

I have tried induction but stuck, so may I ask if it can be done by induction? Or is there any simpler explaination? May I please ask for an explaination?
 Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: May I please ask the assumption that $f_i$'s are irreducible is necessary? May I please ask if why we need it or not.

Comment: I think $E$ needs to be (contained in) the splitting field of $F$.Otherwise, you can take $f \in F$ to split in $F$, and $E$ some nontrivial extension, and then the action of $Aut_F(E)$ is trivial on the roots of $F$, but a nontrivial group.

Comment: @AreaMan E is exacltly the splitting field here. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ideas here:

Call $G$ the automorphism group over $F$ of the splitting field $E$ of $f = f_1 \ldots f_n \in F[x]$. $G = Aut_F(E)$.

1. Each $f_i \in F[x]$ will be fixed by $G$. This implies that it acts on the roots of $f_i$. (Write $f_i = \Pi (x - \alpha_i)$, which is a true equation in $E$[x], then $g \in G$ preserve the polynomial on the left, because its coefficients are in $F$ and thus fixed by $G$. Also the group action preserves the truth of this equation. So all that can happen is that perhaps the $\alpha_i$ get moved around.)
2. If $f_i$ is irreducible, then $G$ will act transivitely on its roots. For this, you have to look at the construction of the splitting field. The feeling is that when you adjoined a root of $f$, you could have adjoined a different one instead, and the result would have been an isomorphic field extension. Then you lift this isomorphism up to the level of the splitting field using the uniqueness of the splitting field. This requires proof and there should be a relevant lemma in your Galois theory text. (This is 18.3 in Isaac's Algebra.)
3. $G$ is determined by its action on the roots of $f$. This is because the roots of $f$ will generate $E$ as a field over $F$ (our assumption that $E$ is the splitting field), and the action of elements in $G$ preserves the field operations and leaves $F$ invariant.

Altogether, $1.$ says we get a map into $Perm(X_1) \times \ldots Perm(X_n)$ and $3.$ says it is injective. I guess 2. is actually irrelevant, but it's good to know anyway. (Why did I write it???)

If is $E$ to be contained in the splitting field for$ f$, its automorphism group is a subgroup of $Aut_F (Split(f))$. (Split(f) is temporary notation for the splitting field.)

Let me know if any needs further clarification.

Comment: If possible, May I please ask for some explanation without the usage of the terminology "Galois Group"？I have recently learnt about automorphism group. But I have not seen the the term "Galois group" yet.

Comment: @PropositionX  The Galois group is the automorphism group $Aut_F(E)$ for $E$ a splitting field of a (separable) polynomial with coefficients in $F$. There are a bunch of equivalent definitions for this special kind of field extension. So you are right, perhaps accidentally, that I may be cheating and assuming the extension is separable, and so calling it the Galois group is not warranted. Will edit.

Comment: In point #3, the roots of $f$ do not generate $E$ as a vector space over $F$; the elements of $E$ *are* $F$-rational functions in the roots, however. In point #1, saying that the action of $G$ ''preserves the truth of this equation" is an odd way to put things. You can be more explicit: if $\alpha$ is a root of $f_{i} = a_{n}X^{n} + \cdots + a_{0}$ and $\sigma \in G$, then $0 = \sigma(0) = \sigma(f_{i}(\alpha)) = f_{i}(\sigma(\alpha))$, where the last equality holds because $\sigma$ is a field automorphism which fixes $F$ (hence the coefficients of $f_{i})$.

Comment: May I please ask how to prove that each $f_i$ is fixed by $G$? How can I see that explicitly?

Comment: @AlexWertheim Of course you're right about category in which they generate, will edit,thanks. Yes that works also ... your explicit point of view is good.

Comment: @PropositionX Yes,the action of $G$ on $f$is the action on the coefficients. But because the coefficients are in $F$, they are fixed by $G$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim By this argument, may I conclude that $\alpha$ is a root of $f_{i}$ if and only if it is a root of $\sigma(f_i(x))$, so after applying the automorphism to each set of root, the set of root of $f_i(x)$ is exactly the same as the set of root of $\sigma( f_i(x))$(That is, the automorphism fixes the set of root of each irreducible factor)?

Comment: Here I cannot see that if some of the conclusion comes from $f_i$ is irreducible, so is it assumption necessary?

Comment: @PropositionX It's just a more refined result. The permutation group of the roots of $f$ contains the product of the permutation groups of the roots of each $f_i$. The result is that in fact that action fixes the set of roots of each $f_i$, for each irreducible component.

Comment: Now I get it. But to find an explicit answer of the question. How can I prove that ther is an injective **Homomorphism** from the automorphism group to the product group? I think as the automorphism is uniquely determined by the permutation of roots, the **injective**part is clear. So how to prove that there exist a homomorphism?

Comment: @PropositionX Being a homomorphism follows because the automorphism group "acts" on the set of roots, in the sense of group action. If $G$ acts on set $Y$, then you get a homomorphism $G \to Aut(Y)$. So let $Y$ be any set. In general you could try to prove, if $G \subset Aut(Y)$ fixes a subset $S \subset Y$ ($gS = S$ for all $g \in G$), then the restriction of the action defines a homomorphism $G \to Aut(S)$. Here the set $Y$ would be the field, and $S$ the set of roots.

Answer (score 1):

I shall assume that $E$ is contained in $E'$, the splitting field of $f$. Then $Aut_F (E) $ is a subgroup of $Aut_F E $. So sufficient to assume $E$ is the splitting field of $f $. Then consider the action of $Aut_{F} (E) $ on the Cartesian product of $X_i $. Each $\sigma \in Aut_F (E) $ permits the elements of $X_i$ and only $1_E $ leaves every element of $X_{i} $ fixed. So there exists an injective map from $Aut_F (E) $ to $Perm (X_1)×Perm (X_2)×....×Perm (X_r) $ suppose $\sigma $ sends an element of $X_i$ to an element of $X_{j}$. Then those two elements are conjugate and hence satisfy both $f_i $ and $f_j $ whence we get $f_i=f_j$ and $X_i=X_j $. But then we can drop  $X_j$ from consideration and the previous arguments go through.

Comment: I think the key point is how to prove that  $\sigma$ permutes elements of $x_i$ only but never send an element of X_i to any other X_i'.

Comment: So may I please ask how to prove it？

Comment: I think this argument does not use the assumption that $f_i$ is irrducible, so is the assumption irrelevant?

Comment: No it does when I say $f_i=f_j$

Comment: Sorry I do not quite understand what is mean by "No it does". May I please ask where do we need the assumption?

Comment: I have learnt that: Automorphism of F preserves roots of any $f(x)\in F[x]$, whenever $f(x)$ is reducible or irreducible.

Comment: When I conclude $f_i=f_j$ this is where we need the assumption. When f_i is irreducible it is the min polynomial of an element od X_i and hence unique. So if x_i and x_j are conjugates they satisfy both f_i and f_j

Comment: When you say conjugate, have you assumed that we are working in the field $\Bbb C$? I think it cannot be assumed.

Comment: In this case, to prove the statement in the question, is it sufficient to prove that for each $f_i$, its set of roots are fixed by $\sigma$, thus we do not need the assumption? That is, is that the case that once we can factorize a polynomial $f(x)$ into factors, no matter they are reducible or irreducible, we always have $Aut_F(E)$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $Perm(X_1)\times ...Perm(X_n)$?

Comment: Or else if we are not in $\Bbb C$, what does it mean by conjugation.

Comment: No I say $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are conjugates in E over F of there exists an F automorphism of E that takes $\alpha$ to $\beta$